# How to represent this in printf format?

Tags: c

I have:

> printf("%.2s\n", &s[2]);

How can I represent that as a chosen value?

So I would want something like:

> printf(%.%is\n", someInt, &s[2]); #
>   but this doesnt work, where %i is someInt

Comment: what O/P do you want actually

Comment: This question is extremely difficult to understand.  If you want to choose the length represented by the 2 in the format string at runtime, then the `%.*s` notation suggested by @Anomie is what you are after; just be careful to ensure that the size actually is a plain `int` and not a `long` or `size_t` or any other type.  You should clarify your question, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `printf("%.*s\n", someInt, &s[2]);`. Consult the [printf man page](http://manpages.debian.net/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=printf&apropos=0&sektion=3&manpath=Debian+6.0+squeeze&format=html&locale=en) for more details.

Comment: Well done for reading through an opaque question!  I agree that your surmise is likely what the poster is after, though it is far from clear from the question.

Answer (score 0):

I am confused about your question but I think you want
printf("%d.%s\n",someint,&s[2]);